# How to update ear in websphere?

Tags: websphere

I've got an application (ear) installed in Websphere. Working fine.

I've setup a monitoring folder in websphere, where "deploymentProperties.props" is monitored for changes. Working fine.

My target is, that my application (ear) in websphere is updated, when "deploymentProperties.props" is changed. The change is triggered, but the update process does not work.

Propertyfile:

```
#
# Header
#
ResourceType=Application
ImplementingResourceType=Application
ResourceId=Deployment=nameOfApplication

# Properties
Name=nameOfApplication
Update=true
operationType=update
contentType=app
contentFile=C:\Folder\nameOfApplication.ear
useDefaultBindings=true
```

SystemOut.Log:

com.ibm.ws.management.wasresource.common.WASResourceException: com.ibm.ws.management.wasresource.common.WASResourceException: com.ibm.ws.management.wasresource.common.WASResourceOperationException: java.lang.Exception: Application install/uninstall failed ADMA5069E: ..

ADMA5069E: The installation of application {0} failed. This application was in the middle of a full update and therefore is uninstalled from the configuration session. Discard your current configuration session immediately to recover the application. Do not save changes to the WebSphere Application Server configuration repository. The application is not uninstalled from this repository. Until the current configuration session is discarded you do not see this application in the current session.

ErrorLog:

ADMA0128E: Invalid cell name was passed to the installApplication API for installing application {0}

Weird: When I try to update same ear, as the one already installed, the update process results with success.

Any hints?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to [this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_config_prop_app.html), you're missing the variable `CreateDeleteCommandProperties=true` in the properties file.

Comment: You said "When I try to update same ear, as the one already installed, the update process results with success.", exactly what wsadmin command(s) are you running to do that update?

Comment: "applyConfigProperties", is running, when WS is detecting any changes in deploymentProperties.props

Comment: This works as expected when I try it.  When you run AdminTask.applyConfigProperties from wsadmin, what do you get?